# How can I replace in a character vector specific strings with the corresponding strings of a second one?

Tags: r, str-replace

I'm tring to lemmatize a vector in R:
I have then a "raw" vector (ex. `c("Marc goes to the park","Marc went to the park",...)`); a database where for each "token" in the token vector (ex. `c("Marc","goes","to",...,"went",...)` there's a "lemma" in the lemma vector (ex. `c("Marc","go","to",...,"go",...)`.

I'da like to transform the "raw" vector a "clean" one that should look like this: `c("Marc go to the park","Marc go to the park",...)`

Here's the code I tried:

```
raw   <- c("meno pressioni", "meno pressione", "men Pressioni")
token <- c("meno", "pressioni", "pressione", "men",  "Pressioni")
lemma <- c("meno", "pressione", "pressione", "meno", "pressione")
for(i in 1:length(token)){
clean <- str_replace(raw, pattern=token[i], replacement=lemma[i])
}
clean

Here is the vector I obtained:

clean
[1] "meno pressioni" "meno pressione" "men pressione" 


And here what I wanted to obtain:

clean
[1] "meno pressione" "meno pressione" "meno pressione"
```

What can I do?

Also thanks to the advices by Haiden, here's the solution that worked for me (using rebus library).

```
for(i in 1:length(token)){raw<-str_replace(raw,pattern=or(START,SPC)%R%raw[i]%R%or(SPC,END),replacement=" "%R%lemma[i]%R%" ")}
```

Comment: I am not able to replicate your error; it has probably to do something with your particular token vector. Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm going to edit my post..

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration of the for loop defines clean, using raw as an argument. However, raw is not redefined in the loop, so each time you run the loop, it looks at the same raw. In other words, running

```
for(i in 1:length(token)){
     clean <- str_replace(raw, pattern=token[i], replacement=lemma[i])
}
```

is exactly the same as running

```
clean <- str_replace(raw, pattern=token[length(token)], replacement=lemma[length(token)])
```

The following then will work.

```
clean<-raw
for(i in 1:length(token)){
     clean <- str_replace(clean, pattern=token[i], replacement=lemma[i])
}
```

However, watch out as the 'men' in 'meno' will also be replaced with 'meno,' meaning the output will be

```
> clean
[1] "menoo pressione" "menoo pressione" "meno pressione"
```

So you'll want to tell str_replace to check word boundaries as such:

```
clean <- str_replace(clean, pattern=paste0("\b", token[i], "\b"), replacement=paste0("\b", lemma[i], "\b"))
```

I'd also recommend running tolower() on clean before initiating the loop, thus eliminating the need to replace both 'pressioni' and 'Pressioni.'

Comment: Thank you, I succeeded in my task. Just one thing to say: your last code didn't work with my datas, I'm doing to edit my post in order to show how I solved.